# How to center children in custom constraint layout programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, view

been at this for a while. Basically I want the views inside my custom ConstraintLayout to be centered programmatically.

My layout looks like this:

```
class CenterLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs,defStyleAttr) {

    private val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()


    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()

        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            setConstraints(child)
        }
        constraintSet.applyTo(this)
    }

    private fun setConstraints(view:View){
        constraintSet.clone(this)
        constraintSet.centerHorizontally(view.id,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
        constraintSet.centerVertically(view.id,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID)
    }
}
```

Basically I loop through the children and apply some consstraints, but it doesn't seem to be working. The views are still anchored top left.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try accesing the layout params of the child view:

```
class Test(context: Context) : ConstraintLayout(context, null, 0) {
    private fun setConstraints(child: View) {
        val params = child.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        params.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        params.endToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
        child.layoutParams = params
    }
    
    override fun addView(child: View?) {
        super.addView(child)
        child?.let { setConstraints(it) }
    }
}
```

Also note how i override the addView method for get the child view added to the layout.

Ignore my constructor just take importance on the methods.

Note: I have not tested this code.